# Return results when I dont have the field name

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to filter some data for a given value but I do not have the field name. For example, I want to return third party vendors with a specific tier; tier1, tier2, etc. So I need to do a `WHERE` at the table level instead of field. Is this possible when I have the table name? Is it possible without the table name in a given schema? I tried the * in the `WHERE` but that doesn't work.

```
 SELECT * FROM vendor v WHERE v.* LIKE('%tier%')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Standard SQL won't do it. It's possible depending on SGDB implementation and will differ from solution to solution. Please specify which SGDB you are using.

Comment: @dvm I am in an oracle db.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? Actual data in certain tables? Or are you trying to identify certain tables that have certain columns?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I am trying to find actual data filtered for the given tier.

Comment: Select from the table.  Read the columns names.  Plug the appropriate one into the query.

Comment: You can't use `*` anywhere other than `select` in standard SQL.

Comment: In Oracle this would be possible in a PL/SQL, function or procedure. You would select all fields (of COLUMN_TYPE='VARCHAR2') from all_tab_columns from the table you have (TABLE_NAME='YOURTABLE') then mount a dynamic sql query, execute it with execute immediate command and return a table or a cursor and do a select from it

Comment: What you mean by `you don't know the column name`? is your column name coming from application code?

Comment: @Rahul I'm new to the schema and just don't know which field it is in.

Comment: You know the table name right? it's `vendor `. Do a `select *` and go through the records to find out.

Comment: @Rahul I am doing that, just looking for a faster alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle SQLPlus and many Oracle query tools, DESCRIBE command gives a description of the table structure, with their field names such that you can then write queries.

DESC is an abbreviation for the command.

```
SQL> desc vendors
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 SLA                                                VARCHAR2(10)
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(100)
```

Even without DESCRIBE you can do the following from any SQL tool to generate a single row with column headers:

```
select * from vendors where rownum = 1;
```

If that isn't good enough, and say you have a huge number of columns, you can generate a bunch of SQL statements from the data dictionary, regarding this table.

```
set head off
select 'select * from '||table_name||' where '||column_name||' like ''%tier%'';'
 from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'VENDORS' and data_type like 'VARCHAR%';

-- Results
select * from VENDORS where DESCRIPTION like '%tier%';
select * from VENDORS where SLA like '%tier%';
```

Then copy-paste and run them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause checks if there are one or more columns like tier

```
SELECT * FROM vendor 
WHERE
    (( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM user_tab_cols
      WHERE table_name = 'vendor' AND column_name LIKE '%tier%') >0 )
```